# Custom image for NING network users provided by an admin

Tags: php, ning

I'm working on a NING network and I wish to develop small application so that I can put a photograph/GIF/animation on "MY PAGE" page - different for each member. It should work simply like: admin puts in the desired username and the bond towards the image file. Member can't be able to remove or modify this image.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Ning App](http://developer.ning.com/docs/opensocial/1.0/ning-apps/anatomy.html) with a [profile view](http://developer.ning.com/docs/opensocial/1.0/ning-apps/anatomy.html#profile-view), this will give you a spot on every member's profile page to add your custom photo. Ning Apps live on your infrastructure so you can build a custom administration interface that works best for your client.